# Should I ask architectural questions on CodeReview?

Tags: discussion

In a scenario when I have lots of code or even when I don't have much yet, but the sole problem concerns the code architecture or design pattern etc. should I then ask such question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Our [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) includes the following part in the [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) section:

> #### Higher-level architecture and design of software systems
>
> We review code, not concepts, diagrams, or outlines. Whiteboard-style
>   questions [may be suitable on Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) if they are
>   specific.

According to this asking about just the design and not a concrete, existing, working implementation is unfortunately off-topic here.

---

If, on the other hand you do already have working and fully implemented code and want to know how it could have been designed better, this would be on-topic. You can mention in your question that you care mostly about the design. However, reviewers are still free to comment on any and all parts of your code regardless.

Therefore it might make sense to make sure it e.g. follows your languages style guide so that there is not too much distracting from your actual question.

Comment: I was thinking about Software Engineering too. Thanks for confirmation.

Comment: This doesn't accurately answer "In a scenario when I have lots of code" aspect of the question. Which is on-topic, but may not get answered.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Well, if there is lots of code, but it's not yet working, that would also be off-topic, of course. But I added a section about the case where the code actually works and the OP still wants the design reviewed.